# GUI XML Comparison tool that parses the XML before diffing for Linux

Tags: xml, linux, diff, file-comparison

I am looking for an XML comparison tool that will parse the XML before diffing for Linux (RHEL 5.7, Gnome). The files that I am diffing are 99% different in a line comparison but 85% the same after parsing.

- I have found ExamXML Pro which appears to be a tool that does the job well. It is Windows only though.
- OxygenXML Diff is built for Linux but does not seem to be able to handle XML that is arranged in a different order but structured the same.

There are many questions on Stack overflow about XML diffing or comparison tools but most are older or not specific to the Linux environment.

Comment: DiffDog from Altova does make assosiation between the nodes but is a windows only app.  Eclipse file comparison is similar to DiffDog but is less thorough.  The only application that I have found that does the job well is ExamXML.

Comment: I am curious why a moderator deleted my answer, which answered the question.